# Auto-write asterisks in C++ comments

Tags: vim

Is there a way for me to configure my vimrc so that, when writing a multi-line comment in C++, Java, or other languages, like

```
/* f
 * o
 * o
 */
```

, I could get the asterisk and space to appear whenever I'm in a comment and press return to start a new line?

If I have not worded my question well enough, please tell me.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is controlled via `'formatoptions'`:

```
:set formatoptions+=r
```

To also enable this for `o` and `O` commands:

```
:set formatoptions+=o
```

See all available options at `:help fo-table`.

Note that this depends on the correct `'comments'` setting, but the default already has the right definition for `/* ... */` multiline comments.